# SUM of rows with column category in mysql

Tags: mysql, sum

I have table in mysql like following

**Table Data :**

```
   id        items     color        date
    1          22       blue      2014-05-25
    2         344       yellow    2014-05-26
    3         255       blue      2014-05-26
    4         234       blue      2014-05-26
    5         200       yellow    2014-05-27
    6         100       blue      2014-05-27
    7         100       yellow    2014-05-25
    8         233       blue      2014-05-26
```

I need sum of items based on color with Grouped by Date ...

like

**I NEED OUTPUT LIKE THIS:**

```
Date        Items    blue  yellow
2014-05-25    122      22   100
2014-05-26   1066     722   344
2014-05-27    300     100   200
```

I need Mysql Query to get output given in above..

Comment: Is there only ever going to be blue and yellow? If so, then the answers below are great. If you want a scalable solution, I'd suggest returning a simple, grouped result and handling the display in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do normal group by Date
and according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html
you should

```
select Date, sum(items) as Items, 
sum(case when color = 'blue' then color else 0 end case) as blue,
sum(case when color = 'yellow' then color else 0 end case) as yellow
from ...
group by Date
```

Sorry if syntax's missmatched. I don't do MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    Table1.Date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.color='blue' THEN Table1.items ELSE 0 END) AS blue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.color='yellow' THEN Table1.items ELSE 0 END) AS yellow,
    SUM(Table1.items) AS Items
FROM
    Table1
GROUP BY
    Table1.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT date, sum(items), sum(if(color='blue',items,0)) as blue, sum(if(color='yellow',items,0)) as yellow
FROM `Table`
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC
```